# a short answer on a question "Could you wait for a moment?"

Tags: modal-verbs, responses

Is it right that on a question: "Could you wait for a moment, please?"
I can't say: "I could", only "I can" because "could" in my answer will be about the past. What else short answers with modal verbs are appropriate here?  Could I say "I will"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here 'Could' is the beginning of a polite request phrased as a question, not a real question. An appropriate answer might be "Yes", "OK", "All right", "Sure", etc. An answer using a modal verb (apart from e.g. "I can" or "I will") might be unusual or incorrect, for example "I could" would probably sound sarcastic.

[Requests (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/requests)

Comment: So, the answer with a modal verb is needless here, isn't it?

Comment: No. "I **can**" is a perfectly good answer using a modal verb - as would be "[Of course] I **will**". Michael just means that *in the exact cited context*, echoing back the "polite **possibility**" reference of the original question is likely to be interpreted as implying "I'm **capable** of waiting - but whether or not I **will** wait is another question that I'm not currently answering".

Comment: "I can" or "I will" are perfectly acceptable, but a rather formal compared with "OK" or "sure." On the other hand, in British English "I could" means "I am physically capable of waiting, but I am not going to wait, and how you deal with that is your problem, not mine."